# [Vue Warn]: Property "0" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, warnings, vue-composition-api

I am pretty new to Vue3, I'm building a small Onboarding portal with Vue and I am using a global state inside my "App.vue" file called `const progressStage = ref(0)` and based on that state rendering specific components.

I also have to emit handlers being passed though to change the state of progressStage

View code here:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
import ComponentA from 'components/componentA.vue' (moc components)
import Component B from 'components/componentB.vue'
const progressStage = ref(0)
const data = ref({})
function handleNavigation(newVal){
  progressStage = newVal
}
function handleClientDataAdd(newData){
 const newData = {...data.value,newData}
 data.value = newData;
} 
</script>

<template>
<ComponentA
v-show:progressStage === 0
/>
<ComponentB
@handle-page-nav="handleNavigation"
@handle-client-data="handleClientDataAdd"
v-show:progressStage === 1
/>
</template>
```

Inside My ComponentB ->
Also The one the error is being called on:
**at <ComponentB onClientDataAdd=fn onHandlePageNav=fn
at App.**

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
const emits = defineEmits(['handlePageNav','clientDataAdd']

const data = ref({
name:''
}) (mock object)
</script

<template>
<input v-model="data.name" />
```

I have multiple other components using the state aswell to dynamically mount themselves, but it seems ComponentB is constantly (on every keystroke in input) throwing the warning mentioned above

**Would appreciate some help**

Answer (score 2):

The first error is `v-show:progressStage === 0`. Change it to: `v-show="progressStage === 0"`.
Docs: [v-if on template](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-on-template).

And `<ComponentB />` has emits `clientDataAdd` but you call event: `handle-client-data`. Change it to: `@client-data-add="handleClientDataAdd"`